# Ionic 5 Angular 9: Observable - Behavior Subject - State Management

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable

I have the problem that I assign a new value to a variable in a detail page, which is then also stored in the LocalStorage. But when I navigate back to the main page, the old value of the variable is still there and not the new value. Only after a reload I get the newly set (latest) value on the main page.

To solve this, I have tried Observables in failure. I do not know how to set up observables, nor do I know how to use them in conjunction with LocalStorage.

After having tried many approaches from the internet, I give up now and hope for your help. 
MANY THANKS!

Comment: Can you post your code? You can use RxJs and a service to get what you want.

Comment: It was a mess, so I erased everything about it.